# Finding an expression to write every odd square with one positive integer variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Every odd number is one difference from an even number, since every even number is a multiple of two we can write it as $2n$, where $n$ is a positive integer ($1,2,3,\dots$) that means an odd number is either $2n+1$ (where $n$ can be $0$) or $2n-1$ (where $n>0$).

An even multiplied into an even is even, since

$2b \times 2c= 4k=2a (a=2k), b,c,k$ are positive integers too.

An odd multiplied into an even is even, since

$2b\times(2c+1)=4bc+2b=2(2bc+b)=2a (a=2bc+b)
$
An odd multiplied into an odd is odd, since

$(2b+1)(2c+1)=4bc+2b+2c+1=2(2bc+b+c)+1=2a+1 (2bc+b+c=a)$

So we want to find every odd square, sounds trivial, boring and infinite.

We have $2x+1=k^2$,  where $x$ is a positive integer $(0,1,2,3,\dots)$

Rearranging we get

$2x=k^2-1$

Using the difference of two squares we get:

$2x=(k-1)(k+1)$

Since we know $k$ is odd since the only time we get an odd by multiplied two numbers is when both of them are odd, so one above and one below an odd is a multiple of two.

We get:

$2x= (2v)(2b)$ where $2v=k-1, 2b=k+1$

We get $2x=4vb$, assuming $vb=a$

$x=2vb$

which means $x$ can only ever be an even number since $2$*(any integer)=even. So that means every odd square can be written as $4t+1$?
When $x=4, 4\times4+1=9, k=3, t=1$
So when $x=8, t=2, 2\times8+1=18$ but that isn't a square,
What about $1$? can we write $1$ in this form? $t=0$ anyways.
25? $4\times6+1$ which means $k=5, x=12, t=6$.

$2x+1=(2s+1)^2=4s^2+1+4s= 4(s^2+s)+1$
$x=2(s^2+s)$

I don't really know how to formalize a linear equation to express all odd squares using a single positive integer variable, can I get some help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is the answer not $(2n-1)^2$ where $n$ is a positive integer?  This gives all the odd squares and nothing else

Comment: @Henry 2x+1=(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1

x=2(n^2+n) which means x should only be even, and n^2+n doesn't map out all integers as a linear function im looking for something with the form of pn+s, no powers above 2, n^2+n, n=1, n^2+n=2, n=2, n^2+n=6, doesn't help much

Comment: Since the odd squares are not evenly spaced, you can NOT form a linear that describes them all. As said by Henry, a quadratic is possible.

Comment: @MohammedBenshams It is indeed true that every odd square is one more than double an even number: for example $121=2\times 60+1$, $169=2\times84+1$, $225=2\times 112+1$, etc.

Comment: Every odd square is $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I guess that is what the OP is looking for... perhaps an answer with the proof should be of help for the OP (not saying it as something mandatory - it's upto you).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A016754 for more information related to odd squares.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your work, but to tell you the truth, there is indeed a way to express squares of odd numbers in a linear form. As Geoffery Tang has pointed it out in his comments, the form is $n^2 = 8k + 1, n$ is odd.
Now how did we arrive here? Notice that you can have every odd number as $n = 2x - 1$. Squaring, you get $n^2 = 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 4(x(x-1)) + 1$. You can again see that be $x$ odd or even, $n(n-1)$ is always even (or try doing it yourself - take $x = 2y$ or $x = 2y - 1$; you'll see that the expression is always divisible by $2$). Thus you can substitute $2k$ for $n(n-1)$ and thus you'll arrive at $n^2 = 8k + 1$.

Now try substituting different values for $k$, you shall see that only those values that are of the form $\frac{x(x-1)}2$ satisfy the condition that the number obtained by the substitution is an odd square. I say, the $4n + 1$ form also works(as you must have observed in this answer), provided that $n$ is a product of two consecutive numbers. And perhaps making the last part a bit more clear by editing should draw even more answers and perhaps one that should satisfy your doubt (not because I'm lazy, it's because it's bedtime here at this moment, so yeah, this is all I can do for you now).

Also, note that the set of odd squares can't have a generalized linear rule, but as Henry has pointed out, a quadratic form is even more viable.